# Convert string to User pk after posting a form with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a feature with AJAX and DRF whereby a user can follow another user. However when I initiate it, the POSTed data does not appear to be hitting the DRF endpoint so I am getting no errors beyond:

```
{user: ["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."],…}
following_user: ["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]
user: ["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]
```

When I hardcode in a couple of integers to the AJAX call it works, so I just need to convert the usernames which are passed as strings to their relevant IDs, I don't know how to do this, however.

Here is my js function:

```
const followUser = function(followedUser){
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var currentUser = 'ben'
    console.log(followedUser);
    console.log(currentUser)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/userconnections/',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value,
            'user': currentUser,
            'following_user': followedUser
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Successfully Followed')
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('ERROR')
            console.log(jqXhr)
        },
    });
}
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class UserConnectionListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    following_user = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserConnections
        fields = ['user','following_user']

class UserConnectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserConnections
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is my models.py file

```
class UserConnections(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is the views function:

```
class UserConnectionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserConnectionListSerializer
    queryset = UserConnections.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """IF this is a form post, use the basic serializer that
        deals with id (primary key) otherwise give the more sophisticated 
        version that deals with actual username"""
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return serializers.UserConnectionSerializer

        return self.serializer_class

        def follow_user(request):
            if request.method == "POST":
                data = {'user': request.DATA.get('user'), 'following_user': request.DATA.get('following_user')}

                serializer = UserConnectionListSerializer(data=data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `POST` request, your `UserConnectionSerializer` will be used. This serializer will have the `user` and `following_user` as `PrimaryKeyrelatedField`. This means you need to pass Id's for `user` and `following_user` and those will be converted to actual objects. From the code it's not clear where the `follow_user` method is getting invoked but you can rewrite the code this way:

```
 def follow_user(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            serializer = UserConnectionSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```